# Referencing a method in the current object

Tags: objective-c

How do you reference a method in the current object in Objective-C?  Is there something like in Java, the *this* keyword?

Here is some fake code to clarify:

```
@implementation FooBard
- (void) foo {
   i = 1
   m = [this bar: i];
}

- (int) bar: int j {
   k = j - 1;
   return (k);
}
@end
```

In Java I would just do **this.bar()** and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m = [self bar:i];
```

Comment: Short and sweet as it was ;-)

Answer (score 2):

All Objective-C methods get an implicit parameter called `self` that is a stack variable of type `id` that points to the current instance. In fact, any C function can be used as an Objective-C method if its first two parameters are type `id` and `SEL` (see below).

`self` is not a reserved keyword in Objective-C like `this` in Java. You can, for example reassign `self` within the method. This is a standard pattern in `init` methods:

```
-(id)init {
  if( (self = [super init]) ) {
    // do initialization here
  }

  return self;
}
```

but reassigning `self` is rarely used in any other context.

You can use `self` like any other variable of type `id`: `[self bar:i]` in the example you provide.

For completeness, all Objective-C methods also get an implicity parameter named `_cmd` as well which is the selector (type `SEL`) of the method being called. See the [Objetive-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for more info.

Comment: _cmd is a good one to use in NSLog statements. such as NSLog(@"%s: my message and object: %@", _cmd, myObject);